# Replace shared properties of javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have two javascript objects, which share several properties.

```
var object1 = {"prop1":"a", "prop2": "b", "prop3":"c"};
var object2 = {"prop2":"d", "prop4": "e", "prop5":"f"};
//replace shared properties here
//maybe using object.hasOwnProperty???
return object1;
//desired output: {"prop1":"a", "prop2": "d", "prop3":"c"};
```

I would like to use `object1` as a template to return a set of filters to my user, however, filters may change, and those changes would be saved to object2. I am trying to **update properties in object1 with those in object 2, only if they exist in both objects.** In this example, for instance, I want to take default values of `prop1` and `prop3`, use object2's value of `prop2`, and ignore `prop4` and `prop5`. 
I could easily loop through the properties of object1 and check if they're in object2, but I feel like there must be an easier way to do this (similiar to `union()` or `intersection()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var object1 = {"prop1":"a", "prop2": "b", "prop3":"c"}
var object2 = {"prop2":"d", "prop4": "e", "prop5":"f"}

function mergeCommon (a, b) {
   return Object.keys(a).reduce((obj, prop) => {
     if (prop in b) obj[prop] = b[prop]
     return obj
   }, a)
}

console.log(mergeCommon(object1, object2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build your output by iterating on the keys of `object1` and using the values of `object2` when they exist.

```js
var object1 = {"prop1":"a", "prop2": "b", "prop3":"c"};
var object2 = {"prop2":"d", "prop4": "e", "prop5":"f"};

var output = {};

Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(k) {
  output[k] = (object2[k] === undefined ? object1 : object2)[k];
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: If `object2.prop2` is falsey, it won't propagate to `object1.prop2`.  (Try with `var object2 = {"prop2":0, "prop4": "e", "prop5":"f"};`

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thanks! That's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be:

```js
const object1 = {"prop1":"a", "prop2": "b", "prop3":"c"};
const object2 = {"prop2":"d", "prop4": "e", "prop5":"f"};
for (const key in object1) {
  if (object1.hasOwnProperty(key) && object2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    object1[key] = object2[key];
  }
}
console.log(object1);
```

Comment: I beat you by just 1 second

Comment: @Tyrsius well done. I guess your answer would be considered more "modern" too.